# What Exactly is the Meaning of "Fatal"?

Tags: word-usage

My understanding is that in its normal usage, it means "deadly."

But the root word of "fatal" appears to be "fate," rather than anything that has to do with "death." In this regard, "fatal" resembles "fateful."

Could "fatal" be a variant of "fateful," perhaps with the "deadly" connotations alluded to above?

Comment: It's totally normal that words change meaning, often getting a more "trivial" meaning.  "Decimate" has a specific meaning, but (sadly) it is now almost always used to mean "destroyed."  "Awesome" has a specific meaning but is now almost always used to mean just "terrific".  the etymology of a word is always an interesting question, but has **no connection at all** to how it is used now (I mean to say, there's no "law" about how it is used now, relating to etymology).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Fatal* does indeed derive from the same root as *fate* [according to the online etymological dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fatal).  The original meaning "belonging to or appointed by fate" is still valid if rare according to Chambers, but seems to have mostly taken on the darker, doom-laden shades of *fate.*

*Fateful* is a different adjective deriving from *fate*.  It means "charged with fate" (i.e. full of fate/doom, the usual result of tacking on the suffix *-ful*) rather than "possessing the qualities of fate" (the usual result of tacking on *-al*).

To complete the set of adjectives, let's not forget *fated*.  It's a perfectly good doom-laden word, after all.

Answer (score 9):

This is an interesting question.  Fatal originates from Latin *fatalis*, meaning something like *pertaining to fate*. It is not so deadly, per se, but then if we examine what *fate* means, things become a little clearer:

> - something that unavoidably befalls a person; fortune; lot
> - the universal principle or ultimate agency by which the order of things is presumably prescribed; the decreed cause of events; time.
> - that which is inevitably predetermined; destiny: Death is our ineluctable fate.

So it makes sense that fatal and fate are connected, since death is the ultimate fate of all living things.

Now *fateful* on the other hand, is also from the same root, but the -ful changes the meaning from something like *pertaining to fate* to something like *characterized by fate*.  In other words, rather than representing our ultimate destiny, *fateful* describes something that has some sort of significance with regard to our fate.  So *fateful* is not as deadly as *fatal* because it contributes to or furthers us toward our fate, rather than being our fate.

Comment: +1 Christianity (and thus the philosophy prevalent in the English-speaking world) was kinda fixated on these concepts the last few centuries. It should surprise no one that some of it bled into the language.

Answer (score 4):

> Could "fatal" be a variant of "fateful," perhaps with the "deadly" connotations alluded to above?

Yes, which is emphasized by the fact that one of the rarer meanings of 'fatal' is 'decisively important; fateful'.  In fact, it's the other way round: 'fateful' (1705–1715) is actually formed from 'fate' (1325–1375), which shares a similar heritage with 'fatal' (1350–1400); namely, the Latin 'fātālis' which unsurprisingly means 'of fate'.

As something which terminates life is to be that life's ultimate end, or fate, the word 'fatal', understandably, often describes that which causes the termination to occur.

Answer (score 3):

You're right about the etymology - from the [Online Etymological Dict.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fatal):

> late 14c., "decreed by fate," from
>   M.Fr. fatal (14c.) and directly from
>   L. fatalis "ordained by fate," from
>   fatum (see fate); sense of "causing
>   death" is early 15c.

Going a bit further back, we might look at the ancient Greek [Moirai](http://www.biocheminfo.org/moirai/ling_yellow/fates.html) - the three Fates:

**Klotho** combs the wool and spins the thread of life.

**Atropos** weaves the thread into the fabric of one's actions.

**Lachesis** determines the length of the thread and thus the period of one's life.

And this classical conception of fate thus sees one's life as a coherent whole, a totality, and from there it's a skip and jump to mortality in a general sense.