# A fatal accident vs a fateful accident

Tags: word-choice, expressions, idioms

- [fatal](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=fatal%20meaning&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=)/adjective/causing death.
- [fateful/adjective](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=fateful%20meaning&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=)/ having far-reaching and often disastrous consequences or implications.

My team-leader survived a life-threatening injury, when back to work, an e-mail that he sent stated-

-I survived a fateful accident.
Apparently, he used it instead of fatal on quite a few occassions.

- In any normal context, is "fateful accident" idiomatic?
- Does it connote to the same as fatal?

Comment: If he survived then it wasn't *fatal*.  If the accident had far-reaching, disastrous consequences or implications (e.g., if he was paralyzed, or if he now has a debilitating fear of <whatever he was doing at the time of the accident>) then it might be considered *fateful*.  If, after a complete recovery, life is back to normal, then it was neither fatal nor fateful.

Comment: The two words are quite different.  One could have a "fateful" accident, eg, without any injury at all, if the accident led to some dramatic change in circumstances (positive or negative).  It could have led to your finding a new job, eg, causing a sudden change in the arc of your life.

Comment: I would be quite spooked if someone told me they had a fatal accident. _Fateful_ just means it had a lot of impact. It may mean one was seriously injured, but it might also mean that it had lasting consequences, or a huge mental impact.

Comment: You could say that a fatality is also always fateful but a fateful event isn't always fatal, but I would disagree with you @Jim that an accident one fully recovers from cannot still be fateful. One's ontology or world view can be irrevocably transformed by traumatic events, events from which one has fully recovered, physically, mentally and spiritually. Fateful in this sense means that fate has intervened in one's life and changed that life forever.

Comment: @LittleEva- Then, I would submit that things wouldn't be back to normal- they'd be different.

Comment: Just as an interesting historical point, which emphasises the belief in *destiny* by many people, Hitler, in the opening words to *Mein Kampf*, says he is glad that *destiny* arranged for him to be born at *Braunau am Inn*. The point is that the River Inn formed the border between Austria and Germany, and in his mind it would become his destiny, *shicksal* in German, to unite the two German speaking nations into a single *Reich*.  Most of us (thank God) do not suffer quite such a megalomanic sense of personal destiny, but in a subtle way I think it plays a part in the psyche of many people.

Comment: Yes, if the accident establishes a new normal, then I'd say that was a fateful accident.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/33346/16833

Comment: @Jim - yes, things would definitely be different, my point was that the recovery can be full - physically, mentally, spiritually - one is in full health again but everything has also changed. Not trying to win here, just trying to communicate what is to me an important facet of fateful. :-)

Comment: Ok.  I guess my point is that "recover" means to return to a previous state. And "fully recover" means to return to "exactly" the same state.  If one's world outlook has changed I count that as part of a person's mental aspect (or perhaps spiritually too), and I'd say that they haven't fully recovered mentally.

Comment: @Jim - Different in this sense, one has recovered fully from any debilitation resulting from the accident and the fateful change is experienced as a positive occurrence - one wouldn't return to the self that was before the accident even if one could.

Comment: Yep, I'd call that fateful.

Comment: @Jim - "If he survived then it wasn't fatal." Not for him, but if someone else died, it would be referred to as fatal.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Sure, but nothing in the question indicates that anyone died in the accident, and even the phrasing of the quote from the email would be odd in my mind if it failed to mention a fatality.

Answer (score 9):

Both ***fatal*** and ***fateful*** derive from the notion of ***fate***.

***Fate*** per the OED is:

> The principle, power, or agency by which, according to certain
>   philosophical and popular systems of belief, all events, or some
>   events in particular, are unalterably predetermined from eternity.
>   Often personified.

It derives from the Latin *fatum* -  (lit) that which has been spoken.

However ***fatal*** and ***fateful*** have come to have very different meanings in modern English.

Whilst ***fatal*** often involves death *(as in a fatal accident)*, it always implies failure and disaster.

The OP's definition of ***fateful***  'having far reaching and disastrous consequences or implications' appears to be taken from Oxford Dictionaries OnLine.  However, the OED, which is far more detailed, provides many senses of ***fateful*** including the one which I think is most important to today's usage.

Whilst ***fatal*** seems to have lost its link to ***fate*** (in the sense of *destiny*), ***fateful*** in my view retains a strong idea of *destiny*. That is not evident from the ODO.  But if you look at sense 3 of ***fateful*** per the OED it says this:

***Marked by the influence of fate; controlled as if by irresistible destiny.***.

The following are all five of the senses of ***fateful*** per the OED. I am speaking for myself as a British person (born 1944) when I say that senses 1 to 3 are the most significant to me. That does not appear to me to be the same as the view taken by the ODO. I am actually quite astonished that the ODO meaning nowhere includes the idea of *fate* or *destiny* in its description of ***fateful***.

**In answer to the OP's direct question, whilst it is possible to survive a *fateful accident* (assuming you believe in fate), the only way to survive a *fatal accident* would be if it was someone else in the car who died, and you were a survivor.**

> 1. Of a voice or utterance: Revealing the decrees of fate; prophetic of destiny.
>
> 1720   Pope tr. Homer Iliad V. xix. 465   Then ceas'd for ever, by the
>   Furies ty'd, His fate-ful Voice.
>
> 1794   S. T. Coleridge Melancholy   A mystic tumult and a fateful
>   rhyme.
>
> 1850   T. Carlyle Latter-day Pamphlets i. 39   That fateful Hebrew
>   Prophecy.
>
> 1863   H. W. Longfellow Tales Wayside Inn ii. Prel. 105   The fateful
>   cawings of the crow.
>
> 1878   B. Taylor Prince Deukalion ii. v. 84   The fateful words, ‘Rise
>   Brother’.
>
> 2. Fraught with destiny, bearing with it or involving momentous consequences; decisive, important. Chiefly of a period of time.
>
> 1800   S. T. Coleridge tr. Schiller Death Wallenstein iii. viii. 92
>   A fateful evening doth descend upon us.
>
> 1850   W. Irving Mahomet (1853) ix. 35   The fateful banner of Khaled.
>
> 1861   Romance of a Dull Life xiii. 97   Each minute seemed fateful to
>   her.
>
> 1884   E. P. Roe Nature's Serial Story xii, in Harper's Mag. Nov.
>   907/1   A fateful conference..was taking place.
>
> > 3. Marked by the influence of fate; controlled as if by irresistible destiny.
> >
> > 1876   S. A. Brooke Primer Eng. Lit. 130   The Bride of Lammermoor, as
> >     great in fateful pathos as Romeo and Juliet.
>
> 1885   Pall Mall Gaz. 17 Feb. 6/2   That fateful inability to review
>   their position.
>
> 1891   Times 14 Feb. 7/5   Peasants..begin..their..wanderings from
>   place to place in an aimless, fateful sort of way.
>
> 1891   E. Peacock Narcissa Brendon I. 229   As fateful as a Greek
>   tragedy.
>
> > 4. Bringing fate or death; deadly; = fatal adj. 6.
> >
> > 1764   J. Grainger Sugar-cane iv. 134   Nor fateful only is the
> >     bursting flame.
>
> 1798   Anti-Jacobin 26 Feb. 126/2   Resounds the fateful dart.
>
> 1807   J. Barlow Columbiad iv. 149   The soldier's fateful steel.
>
> 5. Having a remarkable fate; of eventful history.
>
> > 1886   G. T. Stokes Ireland & Celtic Church (1888) 108 (note) ,   This
> >     fateful book is said to be still in existence.

Comment: @Jim Have a look at my edited version.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how strange it is that the asker's definition for 'fateful' completely omitted the concept of fate.

Answer (score 4):

[Fate - The sense of "causing or attended with death" in English is from early 15c.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fatal&searchmode=none)

**The New Fowler's English Usage** -

Fatal and fateful- the words are etymologically
closely related in that they both
**contained or contain the element fate**.

In **times past** ***they shared a number of
senses,*** 'prophetic', 'fraught with destiny', and even 'producing or resulting
in death'.

But the two words have substantially drawn apart. **Now** fatal alone means 'causing or
ending in death' (**a fatal accident**).